# Mediawiki API: Query picture from Wikimedia Commons with parameter "pageid"

Tags: mediawiki-api, wikimedia-commons

The query below using the file name of the picture works flawlessly:
https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=globalusage&gulimit=20&titles=File:Ferrari%20Roma%20in%20Basel.png

If I want to use the Commons Page ID of this picture (found on the [information page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Ferrari_Roma_in_Basel.png&action=info)) there are no results though:
https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=globalusage&gulimit=20&pageids=88733833

**Does anyone know why it doesn't work with *pageids* as parameter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying [www.wikimedia.org](http://www.wikimedia.org), not commons.wikimedia.org. Page IDs are not shared between wikis.

Comment: Thanks! So the right URL for the example above is https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=globalusage&gulimit=20&pageids=88733833